# switching between activity and mapActivity  + entering the location  settings 

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-activity, dictionary

hello again  thank for the answer but that was not what i want

this is the error that it appear when i click on the button

09-15 06:25:41.936: D/error on click(442): here  is the error in the onclick method 
09-15 06:25:41.936: D/error on click(442): here  is the error in the if statement 
09-15 06:25:41.947: D/AndroidRuntime(442): Shutting down VM
09-15 06:25:41.947: W/dalvikvm(442): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-15 06:25:41.957: E/AndroidRuntime(442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 06:25:41.957: E/AndroidRuntime(442): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-15 06:25:41.957: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.androidhive.googlemaps.ShowMap.onClick(ShowMap.java:42)
09-15 06:25:41.957: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-15 06:25:41.957: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-15 06:25:41.957: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-15 06:25:41.957: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-15 06:25:41.957: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-15 06:25:41.957: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-15 06:25:41.957: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 06:25:41.957: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-15 06:25:41.957: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-15 06:25:41.957: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-15 06:25:41.957: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-15 06:25:45.266: I/Process(442): Sending signal. PID: 442 SIG: 9

and this is the code of the button click

```
public void onClick(View v) {

     gps = new NetworkSettings();

     Log.d("error on click ", "here  is the error in the onclick method ");

     if(isGPSEnabled)
     {
     // Log.d("error on click ", "here  is the error in the if statement ");

      Intent intent = new Intent(this, AndroidGoogleMapsActivity.class);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
     }

     Log.d("error on click ", "here  is the error out the if statement ");



         gps.showSettingsAlert();

}
```

and this is the showSettingsAlert() method

public void showSettingsAlert() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

```
    Log.d("error on click ", "here  is the error inthe top of the method ");

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog
            .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");





    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });


    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });


    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

i know that the error is in the click button but i don't know what it is and how to fix it so please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this, mapslayout.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-library
android:name="com.google.android.maps"
android:required="true" />
```

Use like this, error will be solved.